# Implementing a recyclerview with multiple viewolder and data binding library

Tags: android, android-databinding, android-viewholder, recyclerview-layout

I'm trying to use the *databinding library* with a `recyclerview` *with multiple viewholders (with shared elements)*.

I tried solutions that involve casting and generics. Neither worked.

*Is there a way to relate different `ViewDataBinding` classes that link similar `xml` layouts such that they have a sibling relationship?*

Or, *Is there a way to do inheritance in `xml`*? I figure since the `ViewDataBinding` objects are generated (in part) by the `xml`, maybe parent and children `xml` layouts could produce the desired effects?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Make Sure to read my comment below for the solution implemented. I'm marking this as correct because it eventually got me to the correct answer
-Joel**

Hope I understood your problem.
Consider the snippet below.

*parent_xml.xml*

```
<layout>
   <FrameLayout
   ....
   ...
   >

   <!-- including child -->
   <include 
       android:id="@+id/included"
       layout="@layout/child_xml" /> 

   </FrameLayout>
</layout>
```

*child_xml.xml*

```
<layout>
    <View
        android:id="@+id/child_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</layout>
```

You can access child view using..

```
ParentXmlBinding mBinding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(... reference of parent_xml);
mBinding.included.childView.(... Access view method here); // Referring child view
```

Have I answered your question?

Comment: so, I like your idea, but I couldn't find a way to inflate the view (at first). I tried passing in a Integer object with the resource id of the desired layout into the xml, hoping I could create a reference to the layout from the resource id (it didn't work). Then I tried replacing the include tag with a view and then set the view to the View.inflate() output (didn't work). The soln that worked include having multiple include tags that linked to the unique views. I set the visibility of the unique views to View.GONE when I didn't need them.